# Java custom Comparator implementation

Tags: java, comparator

I am writing a Comparator with which I can sort a String array using character count. The Strings are all lowercase ASCII characters.

Eg.

```
input = {"art", "bash", "tar"};
Expected sorted output = {"art", "tar", "bash"};
```

Here, it does not matter if "bash" is at the beginning, but "art" and "tar" should be one after the other, in no particular order as they have matching character count.

I have this code, where I am using a simple array to check and keep the character count and compare.

```
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2){
        if (s1.equals(s2)) return 0;
        
        int[] a1 = getCountArray(s1);
        int[] a2 = getCountArray(s2);
        if (Arrays.equals(a1, a2)) return 0; // character count matches

        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }

    private int[] getCountArray(String s) {
        int[] array = new int[256];
        for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
            array[s.charAt(i) - 'a'] ++;
        }
        return array;
    }

};
String[] input = {"art", "bash", "tar"};
Arrays.sort(input, comparator);
```

However, it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "sort a String array *using character count*"? From what I understand character count should make `art` and `tar` equal, but for some reason you placed `bash` between them which is unclear to me.

Comment: Both of your if conditions needs a closing `)`. In your second if condition there is a missing `s` in `Arrays`.

Comment: Right, sorry, "bash" position doesn't matter. What matters is words with same char. count should be consecutive in no particular order. I have updated the question.

Comment: @MichaelChatiskatzi sorry, corrected. I removed some redundant code around it from my project to make it concise and missed a couple things.

Comment: I suspect that you may be looking for `Arrays.compare` method and use it like `@Override public int compare(String s1, String s2){ return Arrays.compare(getCountArray(s1), getCountArray(s2)); }`. If that does not give you results which you ware expecting then please point out difference between expected and actual result.

Comment: Anyway why are you using `s.charAt(i) - 'a'` at `array[s.charAt(i) - 'a']`? Since your array has `256` length why you want to shift value of index? If you will try to shift character which position is *smaller* than `'a'` then you will end up with negative index.Shifting would make sense if you are sure that you are dealing only with characters in range `a-z` but for them you don't need array of length 256 (since there are less characters in a-z range).

Comment: I was subtracting char a just to have a zero based index, nothing specific about that. Sounds good, let me try with arrays compare!

Comment: @Pshemo I don't see a `compare` defined for `java.util.Arrays`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It was introduced in Java 9 https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#compare(int[],int[])

Answer (score 2):

Your comparator is not consistent:

- when comparing "art" against "bash" it returns that "art" is smaller than "bash"
- when comparing "bash" against "tar" it returns "bash" is smaller than "tar"
- therefore when comparing "art" against "tar" it **must** return "art" is smaller than "tar" (since "art" < "bash" < "tar"), but your comparator returns "art" is the same as "tar".

When you call `Arrays.sort(input, comparator);` the sort method will do pair-wise comparisons and will always find that "bash" has to be before "tar".

To fix this you must replace `return s1.compareTo(s2)` with something that compares the character count arrays `a1` and `a2`.

Comment: > When you call Arrays.sort(input, comparator); the sort method will do pair-wise comparisons and will always find that "bash" has to be before "tar". 
I think this is what causing the problem and makes sense. Can you explain in a bit more detail, or point me to somewhere I can read about it?

Comment: @Ufder if you want to know how `Arrays.sort()` is implemented you can look directly into the source code. The JDK contains a file "lib/src.zip" with the source code of much of the Java standard library. The sort algorithm is implemented in the class `java.util.TimSort`

Comment: @Ufder there’s no sense in looking into implementation details. You expect the result order `"art", "tar", "bash"` despite your comparator says that `"bash"` is smaller than `"tar"`, which contradicts your expected result. So it can’t work that way. Even if a particular implementation returned the expected result, it implied that you got the result from broken code by chance. You can’t expect reliable results from sorting with an inconsistent comparator.